# How to delete pointers that are elements of an array

Tags: c++, destructor

Below is the code for constructor and destructor. Destructor successfully destructs the array created by option 1. What if we have multiple array as in option 2. Will the same destructor coding is enough to delete or some changing in the code is required.

```
#include "iostream"
class Mystack
{
private:
    int capacity;
    int top[3];
    int *input;//option1        
    int *input[3];//option 2
public:
    Mystack();
    ~Mystack();
    void push(int stackNum, int elem);
    void pop(int stackNum);
    void display();
};

Mystack::Mystack()
{
    capacity = 3;
    top[3] = { -1 };
    input[] = new int[capacity]; //option 1     
    input[3] = new int[capacity];// option 2
}

Mystack::~Mystack()
{
    delete[]input;// Works for option 1. Should it be same for option 2??
}
```

Comment: Neither option would compile.  (Well, option 2 might if `input` has been declared as `int **` or similar, but then that `delete` would leak...)

Comment: Added the other relevant code.

Comment: what do you want to do with `input[]`?

Comment: Ah, ok.  Well Option 1 still won't compile!  And Option 2 will probably seg-fault on construction, and will leak on destruction.  If your general question is "how do I delete an array of pointers to allocated memory?", then the answer is that you'll need to call `delete []` on each pointer in turn.

Comment: @Rinzler : Want to know how to destructor code changes in order to destruct option 1 and option 2.

Comment: @tanz If you want to know how the destructor is going to behave you  need to provide us with _valid working_ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `int *input[3]` is a raw array that will contain pointers to ints, a.k.a `int*`. You have a lot of errors in your code, for example you are accessing the 4th position of the array *top* with `top[3]`, which has just 3 elements, and you are assigning something `{ -1 }` to its imaginary 4th element, instead of an int.

These declarations are also not valid, because you are using the same identifier for 2 different variables:

```
int *input;//option1        
int *input[3];//option 2
```

If you want to delete the memory allocated by an array of pointers, I would iterate through the array calling each time `delete []` on them:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
     delete [] input[i];
```

This is going to free all the memory allocated by the pointer to integers `input[0]`, `input[1]` and `input[2]`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No, because I am actually answering to some problems the OP is having that do no allow him to proceed.

Comment: But you don't address the actual question, which is about the destructor.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No. We cannot even answer its question about the destructor, if the destructor will never be called with his code.

Comment: And that's why this should be a comment.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Down-vote whatever you want. I don't need your fuel. I am just trying to help.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I am pretty sure you are a good person, Oliver.

Comment: I have tried putting option 1 in my code and it seems to work. I have `int *input` and then then destructing it with `delete []input`. So what I understand from this is the memory that input pointer was pointing to gets free. Does it works same way while adding option 2, where I have int *input[3]. Or do I need to use something like `delete [3]input`. Kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth By the way, I hadn't finished with this answer.

Comment: If the question can't actually be answered than you should know _not_ to post something as an _answer_.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious The question can be answered, obviously.

Comment: That contradicts your previous comment.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Does not contradict what I said, and this is true.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious `We cannot even answer its question about the destructor, if the destructor will never be called with his code.` I would like to underline the `if` statement.

Comment: @Rinzler : Actually I had added the option 1 snippet from my other code so that comparison can be made that's why same identifier. I understood now how to delete array of pointers. And thanks for pointing out the error in the "TOP".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth If you down-voted my other `tkinter` and `ttk` related question, that you are really a bad person, if not, then I am sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: @tanz Thanks dude. I am sorry that people here can only understand reputation instead of trying to help :)